# ImportError: Failed to load PyTorch C extensions: on macos

Tags: python, pytorch, anaconda, conda

I am using macos 10.15.6 and Python 3.7.11 through conda 4.12.0.

when executing the line "import torch" in python, I get the following error.

```
raise ImportError(textwrap.dedent('''
ImportError: Failed to load PyTorch C extensions:
    It appears that PyTorch has loaded the `torch/_C` folder
    of the PyTorch repository rather than the C extensions which
    are expected in the `torch._C` namespace. This can occur when
    using the `install` workflow. e.g.
        $ python setup.py install && python -c "import torch"

This error can generally be solved using the `develop` workflow
    $ python setup.py develop && python -c "import torch"  # This should succeed
or by running Python from a different directory.
```

I tried to solve running
**conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=9.0 -c pytorch**
but still didn't solve it.

Comment: There is no CUDA support for the version of MacOS you are using and the error you are experiencing has nothing to do with CUDA.

Comment: thank you, so how could I solve it?